# Custom ClipPath help Flutter

Tags: flutter

Help me to build the following shape, please.

[image]

I've written the following code.

```
class CustomShapeBar extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;
    path.lineTo(0, height - 230);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width / 2, height, width, height - 230);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is what I've achieved:

[image]

Comment: use `arcTo` / `arcToPoint`, not `quadraticBezierTo`